# ggplot unable to recognize most unicodes

Tags: r, ggplot2, unicode, visualization, computer-science

I'm triying to include different figures in a ggplot, but the package is not recognizing unicodes. For example, when I try this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)

ig_5 <- data.frame(
  category = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"),
  prop = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.15, 0.25, 0.05, 0.25)) %>%
  mutate(lab.ypos = cumsum(prop) - 0.5*prop, 
         lab.ypos2 = cumsum(prop) + 0.3*prop)

 
ggplot(ig_5, aes(x = 2, y = prop, fill = prop)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", color = "white") +
  coord_polar(theta = "y", start = 0) +
  geom_text(aes(y = lab.ypos, label = prop), color = "black", size = 5) +
  geom_label(aes(y = lab.ypos,
                 label = "\u26AA"), 
                 vjust = 1.5, 
             color = 'red') +
  xlim(.5, 2.5)
```

I get this:

[image]

Instead of this:

[image]

I obtained the latter picture running the code in DataCamp Workspace.

The problem appears only with ggplot. If I print this: "\u26AA", I get what i should.

```
"⚪"
```

Moreover, the problem is not present in R, only in Rstudio.

My session info is the following:

```
R version 4.3.0 (2023-04-21 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 11 x64 (build 22621)

Matrix products: default


locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Spanish_Ecuador.utf8  LC_CTYPE=Spanish_Ecuador.utf8    LC_MONETARY=Spanish_Ecuador.utf8 LC_NUMERIC=C                    
[5] LC_TIME=Spanish_Ecuador.utf8    

time zone: America/Guayaquil
tzcode source: internal
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It is working fine for me, I am not sure but it may be related to your locale. You can try: `Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL","English")` or may be `Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL","English.utf8")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you witness here is most likely related to graphics backend and font handling. You are using *(Default)* / *Windows* backend, right? (*Tools > Global Options > General > Graphics > Backend*).

Try switching to *AGG* (you may need to install `ragg` package first) and test with:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot() + geom_label(aes(x = 0, y = 0, label = "\u26AA")) + theme_void()
```

Windows renderer probably returns the first image bellow while with AGG you should see the 2nd output.

[image]
[image]

More info and samples here - https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2021/02/modern-text-features/#color-fonts